# Android onClickListener not registering clicks (I think)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a very basic solitaire game. I have buttons set up that are supposed to allow the player to interact with the cards.  I have listeners set on each button, but for the moment I am only working with one of the buttons to try and iron out this problem. I have the onClick() method set up, and listeners set on the button, but when I click the button nothing happens.  I'll try to extract the relevant code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.game);
      playableImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.playableStack);
      deckButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.deckButton);
      deckButton.setOnClickListener(this);

          @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.deckButton:
            System.out.println(playableCards);
            dealCardsToPlayableStack();
            System.out.println(playableCards);  
            playableImage.setImageResource(getCardImageId(playableCards.peekTopCard()));
            playableImage.invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

As requested, here is the xml layout for the activity.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/background" android:baselineAligned="true"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">
      <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="62.5dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/deckImage" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="62.5dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/playableStack" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/spadesStack"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/diamondsStack"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/clubsStack"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/heartsStack"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack1"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack2"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack3"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack4"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack5"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack6"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cardtemplate"
            android:layout_height="62.5dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:padding="2.5dp" android:id="@+id/stack7"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/deck"
            android:id="@+id/deckButton"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/playable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/playableButton"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/spades"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spadesButton"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/diamonds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/diamondsButton"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/clubs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/clubsButton"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hearts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/heartsButton"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack1Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack2Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack3"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack3Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack4"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack4Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack5"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack5Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack6"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack6Button"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/stack7"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/stack7Button"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="@string/numCards" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="40dp" android:text="@string/default_number_of_cards">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you get output on console for the System.out ?

Comment: Is v.getId() and R.id.deckButton are same? I suspect case R.id.deckButton is not getting called.

Comment: Can your post your layout as well? Also, are you implementing OnClickListener?

Comment: I don't get any ouput for the System.out statements. v.getId() and R.id.deckButton are supposed to be the same thing. I think you are right that the case isn't being called, but I can't figure out why. I think I'm doing the onClickListener correctly. I'm implementing it like you would any other interface, and I'm implementing the onClick method.

Comment: What's really bugging me is that I'm using a button to launch this activity and it's working fine, but this one refuses to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to debug using:

```
System.out.println();
```

On android you should use:

```
Log.d("CARDS","LIST OF CARDS");
```

You can then view this info by opening up the logcat view in Eclipse. 
Have a read of this it might help.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you can open up the logcat by going to window>show view>other>under android select logcat and now this will appear as a tab under your view. By clicking this tab it will bring up the log. You can then do stuff such as search for CARDS to find the info I placed in the logcat for the above example.

Comment: I added log statements at the end of my onCreate method and all throughout my onClick method.  None of them show up in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Is you activity implementing OnClickListener?